# Object Detection API List index out of range

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, mobilenet

I'm trying to use the ssd mobilenetv3 object detection model, I found this [tutorial](https://dontrepeatyourself.org/post/object-detection-with-python-deep-learning-and-opencv/)
I tried running the python file on my device using an image I snapped with my phone

but I keep getting this error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IAEU.png)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/nombaadmin/Documents/GitHub/Object-Sorting-Robot/object_sorting.ipynb Cell 17 in <cell line: 29>()
     46     class_id = int(detection[1])
     47     # print (class_id)
     48     # draw the name of the predicted object along with the probability
---> 49     label = f"{class_names[class_id - 1].upper()} {probability * 100:.2f}%"
     50     cv2.putText(image, label, (box[0], box[1] + 15),
     51                 cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
     53 cv2.imshow('Image', image)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code from the tutorial

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('Images/IMG20221220090901.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480))
h = image.shape[0]
w = image.shape[1]

# path to the weights and model files
weights = "frozen_inference_graph.pb"
model = "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt"
# load the MobileNet SSD model trained  on the COCO dataset
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(weights, model)

# load the class labels the model was trained on
class_names = []
with open("labels.txt", "r") as f:
    class_names = f.read().strip().split("\n")

# print(class_names)

# create a blob from the image
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(
    image, 1.0/127.5, (320, 320), [127.5, 127.5, 127.5])
# pass the blog through our network and get the output predictions
net.setInput(blob)
output = net.forward()  # shape: (1, 1, 100, 7)

# loop over the number of detected objects
for detection in output[0, 0, :, :]:  # output[0, 0, :, :] has a shape of: (100, 7)
    # the confidence of the model regarding the detected object
    probability = detection[2]

    # if the confidence of the model is lower than 50%,
    # we do nothing (continue looping)
    if probability < 0.5:
        continue

    # perform element-wise multiplication to get
    # the (x, y) coordinates of the bounding box
    box = [int(a * b) for a, b in zip(detection[3:7], [w, h, w, h])]
    box = tuple(box)
    # draw the bounding box of the object
    cv2.rectangle(image, box[:2], box[2:], (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)

    # extract the ID of the detected object to get its name
    class_id = int(detection[1])
    # print (class_id)
    # draw the name of the predicted object along with the probability
    label = f"{class_names[class_id - 1].upper()} {probability * 100:.2f}%"
    cv2.putText(image, label, (box[0], box[1] + 15),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have tried to check the value of class_id its value is 87 which is above the limit with is 1 to 80

I inputed the image of a spoon I snapped with my phone

Comment: It looks like class_names is populated from labels.txt. How many lines are in that file?

Comment: 80 lines
It's from this document
https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/data/coco.names